# Where can I find my original 'sources.list' file?

Tags: apt, configuration, official-repositories, software-sources

> Note: If you have lost and want to recreate your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, please use the [Ubuntu Source Generator](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/index.php), with the appropriate choices. *Warning: any custom repositories you added to your old `sources.list` (but not PPAs) will be lost.*

Where can the original /etc/apt/sources.list be found?

I know some forum posts and third party sites pasting it's contents, but what is the official source for this file?

It must be somewhere on ubuntu.com?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is generated by the installer.

If you use Ubiquity (the live one), you can see [how](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-installer/ubiquity/trunk/view/head:/scripts/apt-setup) in launchpad.

I didn't dig for the classic installer, `debian-installer`.